# Why does this site not require login after new browser session?

Tags: discussion, login, user-accounts, security

To clarify:

I've set this site to not remember me. This seems to be ambiguous on different sites now as that can either mean to not keep track of my credentials locally and to keep me logged in or to just not do both for a given session.

For example:

When logging into YouTube, I make sure to deselect "Remember me". This, to me, is telling me that it's not storing my credentials in a cookie and that it's not going to keep me logged in if I close my browser and start a new session. This remains true. I have to then provide my credentials again.

When I do that for sites on Stack Exchange however, I'm not given that option.

Logging in, yes, I deselect--however, starting a new session without manually logging out keeps me logged in.

**TL;DR:**

**Why is there no option to not keep me logged in for these sites?**

Call me paranoid, but I don't like it from a security perspective.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Should I go ahead and delete this question?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with having duplicates around.